# How to set lfFaceName by using pywin32

Tags: python, mfc, pywin32

I have an tiny MFC program which is going to be port to **pywin32**.
But I can not manage to handle ***lfFaceName*** of *LOGFONT* object. 
*lfWidth* & *lfHeight* could be easily handled but ***lfFaceName*** not.
I've tried several different ***lfFaceName*** but seems result is same?
This is an example python code fragment which I've tried.

```
lf            = win32gui.LOGFONT()
lf.lfFaceName = "Arial"    #Is this the correct way???

if iWidth < 16:
    lf.lfWidth = iWidth
else:
    lf.lfWidth = iWidth/2
if lf.lfHeight > iHeight:
    lf.lfHeight = iHeight
if lf.lfHeight < iHeight-1:
    lf.lfHeight = iHeight-1

s_Font = win32gui.CreateFontIndirect(lf)
win32gui.SelectObject (s_DC, s_Font)
win32gui.DrawText(s_DC, sText, len(sText),(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight), DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wrong **lfFaceName** had been assigned.There will not be any error indicated but the default FaceName will be used.So an FaceName Enum is needed for this application.
We could get the full **lfFaceName** list by ***FaceName[]***.

```
import win32gui


def callback(font, tm, fonttype, fonts):
    fonts.append(font)
    FaceName.append(font.lfFaceName)
    return True


FaceName = []
fonts    = []
hdc = win32gui.CreateDC('DISPLAY','Display',None)
win32gui.EnumFontFamilies(hdc, None, callback, fonts)
```